# Best practice for multiple resources and one database table in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model-view-controller

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails project. The project has a main database table, called 'Post'.

This table is used for storing questions, answers, comments and announcements as different post types. Currently we use only one model to access the data. But while working on the systems it feels cluttered. Because every post type has some differences.

**What is a best practice:**

1. Split the post resource into different resources, but using only the one Post table for data access?
2. Split the database table into comments, questions, answers and announcements tables; and use resources for each table (model+controller+views)?

Comment: Well I don't think your question will be accepted because not specific enough. Anyway I think it is always better to reflect your data in the database, especially if there are (or there will be) many differences. There are differents ways to see it though : you could store common data in 1 main table and attributes as key/value pairs in another table for example. Or have different tables for each data types as you suggested...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: it depends.

What you're doing now is pretty close to Single Table Inheritance (STI), though it sounds like you're using a single `Post` class which contains all your different behaviors.  STI is a valid approach to storing your model data, but like everything, it has advantages and disadvantages.

My recommendation would be to use separate classes to encapsulate the behavior of separate domain models.  This is the fundamental paradigm in OOP, so I would say it's *probably* a best practice.

Assuming you split your behavior across classes, the question of whether you use a single table to store them or multiple tables really depends on the complexity of your queries and how many common fields there are across your models.  If they share a lot of common fields, STI may work nicely.  If not, you're probably not going to enjoy the overhead of all the extra reads/writes you'll pay.  But all that is really secondary and can be figured out as your app grows and you learn more about the usage patterns.

Try it using STI and see how it goes.  Splitting things up into multiple tables is easier than the opposite, so a migration path is not necessarily too hard.

Comment: Thanks. That's a good recommendation. I listed the structural differences between each post type and I think it is still useful to use one table. There are only 1 or 2 empty columns depending on the post type. I think thats okay for now.

Comment: For that degree of overlap, yes I agree, you are probably fine to use STI.  Keep in mind you can still do resourceful routing/controllers, but your controllers can inherit from a common one.  There's lots of ways to keep things DRY in this setup.  Long term you may end up breaking things up, but it's hard to predict.  It may never be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I think the choise should be based on every certain situation. Just enumerate advantages and disadvantages of each option for you. Points to investigate and make decision could be like: number of differences between each type of entities, the way to access entities, frequency of usage of each type of entities, maintability of code, forecast of changes in the future, and many others.